# python code for parsing mysql-dump file and extract useful data from it

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I'm sorry to tell a bad question, actually I have a set of MySQL dump file and I want to parse these files with Python and extracting valuable information from them.

in parsing operation i have 3 state as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjlZZ.png)

In your opinoin how i can handle this 3 state?

Comment: This is completely incomprehensible. Try adding the supposed input, the expected output, and a pseudocode, at least.

Comment: use [`([^']*)(?=' *\))`](https://regex101.com/r/6KZ5jp/2)

Comment: Most languages -- other than SQL -- have a library that parses JSON; why do you need to do it in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
('BoredMS site, ddos regularly :3')
```

If you really want that exact part!  :)  But I suspect you want the 5th quoted item in the comma separated list.  Give this a shot:

```
(?:[^,]+,){4}\s*('[^']+')
```

To explain that it's 4 sets of items separated by a comma, then maybe spaces, then matching everything between the next set of single quotes.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @Arman farhad if this answer worked for you, can you accept it please? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
\(\d+\,\s*\d+,\s*\'\w\',\s*\'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\',\s*\'(.*)\'\)
```

When I need to create regular expression, I use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)
It helps to create the regexp string and see your example being parsed live.